# Upgrading target SDK to 30 causes 'Cannot resolve symbol org.apache.commons.net'

Tags: android, android-studio, import, apache-commons

I upgraded the target SDK to 30 from 29 in Android Studio, and it causes my FTPClient import to fail with `cannot resolve symbol org.apache.commons.net`

My import is: `import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;`

If i revert the target SDK back to 29, it works fine. I tried to upgrade the implementation in build.gradle but it didn't work:

```
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.8'
```

Is there some change to the import once I change the target SDK to 30?

Comment: Try `implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.4'`

Comment: @blackapps that worked! Thanks, not sure why it worked though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @blackapps,
The following worked:

```
implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.4'
```